# Executing a function for each resolved Promise in Promise.all

Tags: javascript, promise

I am using `Promise.all` to handle multiple promises simultaneously, but I also need to run a function for each resolved promise. The issue I'm facing is that if I pass the function directly to the .then() of the promise, it gets executed immediately, not waiting for the `Promise.all` to trigger it. How can I achieve executing a function for each resolved promise while still using Promise.all? I'm also need get the progress of this Promise.all

```js
async function fetchData(url) {
/***
I want to append a callbackResolve for this fetch, 
but if I use .then() it execute the function and not the Promise.all
**/

  return await fetch(url);
}

const urls = [
  'https://api.example.com/data1',
  'https://api.example.com/data2',
  'https://api.example.com/data3'
];


Promise.all(urls.map(fetchData))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all promises fulfil, `Promise.all` returns a promise that resolves with an array of values --the resolution values of the original promises. So you could just iterate that array and perform the extra logic on them.

Like this:

```
function fetchData(url) {
  return fetch(url);
}

const urls = [
  'https://api.example.com/data1',
  'https://api.example.com/data2',
  'https://api.example.com/data3'
];

const promises = urls.map(fetchData);
Promise.all(promises).then(arr => {
    arr.forEach(callbackResolve);
});
```

To monitor the progress, you *can* use individual `.then()` calls on the original promises. For example, complete the above code like this:

```
function fetchData(url) {
  return fetch(url);
}

const urls = [
  'https://api.example.com/data1',
  'https://api.example.com/data2',
  'https://api.example.com/data3'
];

const promises = urls.map(fetchData);

let resolveProgress = 0;
for (const promise of promises) {
    promise.then(() => {
        resolveProgres++;
        console.log("Progress:", 
                    ((resolveProgress / promises.length) * 100).toFixed(2) + "%"
                   );
    });
}

Promise.all(promises).then(arr => {
    arr.forEach(callbackResolve);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you need to run the function for each resolved promise, call it after `fetchData()` completes for each input:

```js
Promise.all(urls.map(async (url) => {
  const result = await fetchData(url);
  await callbackResolve(url, result);
  await trackProgress(url);

  return result;
}))
```

Running any processing that is specific to one URL on the value returned by `Promise.all()` is incorrect design. It is cumbersome and makes the code difficult to read and understand.